# How to show the image with menu item in Action bar in android

Tags: java, android

I am developing the android application. have one doubt regarding  show the image with menu item  in Action bar in android 
How to show the image with menu item  in Action bar in android 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always|withText"
    android:title="@string/menu_settings"/>
```